# Extract the +(plus) symbol from newtxmath

Tags: fonts, newtxmath

I want to extract the plus symbol `+` from the `newtx`(which included `newtxmath`) package. But I want to just extract this symbol into my document, not to include the entire package (which leads to a conflict). How can I do this? For example, it seems it should be written as something like `\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{...}{...}{...}` to redefine the `+` symbol, but how can I get the font-family name of `newtxmath`? I checked the package document, but can't find it. At the same time, I also checked the `newtxmath.sty`, but hardly to understand. Need help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important lines from `newtxmath.sty` for the redefinition of the plus sign in math are the lines with `\DeclareMathSymbol{+}` and the definitions for the symbol font `lettersA`.

In addition, the font definition file `untxmia.fd` uses `\if` switches that reflects the options `libertine`, `minion`, and `cochineal`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\mathchardef\OldPlus=\mathcode`\+

\makeatletter
\newif\iftx@libertine
\newif\iftx@minion
\newif\iftx@coch
\makeatother
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{lettersA}{253}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Old: & $\OldPlus$\\
  New: & $+$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The case of the minus sign or `\times` is different. Here, package `newtxmath` redefines the standard symbol font `symbols`. Therefore, this font is renamed to `NTXsymbols` in the following example in order to avoid changes of other letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\mathchardef\OldPlus=\mathcode`\+
\mathchardef\OldMinus=\mathcode`\-
\let\OldTimes\times

\makeatletter
\newif\iftx@libertine
\newif\iftx@minion
\newif\iftx@coch
\makeatother
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{lettersA}{253}

\DeclareSymbolFont{NTXsymbols}{OMS}{ntxsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{NTXsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{ntxsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{NTXsymbols}{0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\times}{\mathbin}{NTXsymbols}{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Old & New \\
  \midrule
  $\OldPlus$ & $+$ \\
  $\OldMinus$ & $-$ \\
  $\OldTimes$ & $\times$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! How can I mimic this way to redefine `-` and `\times`? I opened `newtxmath.sty` but can't find the definition of `-` or `\times`. Is there an encode table to see which character is corresponding to which encode?

Comment: @Eric See updated answer.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I can compile successfully but seems LaTeX can't get the font of $-$ and $\times$, they look like traditional Computer Modern style symbols. (So the `-` looks rounded-corner and apparently longer then the `+`). My environment: I use XeLaTeX and `mtpro2` now. I have installed the `newtx` package(the latest version) but don't `usepackage` them. The `+` behaves successfully.

Comment: @Eric Have you loaded `mtpro2` before or after the redefinitions?

Comment: Before. I put my test code to [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58a830490c1aa99941946b71) (ps: the site doesn't support XeLaTeX.)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I can change the command `\DeclareSymbolFont{NTXsymbols}{OMS}{ntxsy}{m}{n}` to `\DeclareSymbolFont{NTXsymbols}{OMS}{ntxsyddvskposdvk}{m}{n}`(a non-existent family name) and pass the compiler. So maybe the reason I can't get the `ntxsy` font is that the compiler fail to load the `ntxsy` font?

Comment: @Eric In the answer, only `symbols`, the first argument of `\DeclareSymbolFont` is changed to `NTXsymbols`. The font mapping must be the same. Otherwise, you get a different font or a default font, if the font does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

In case you do not wish to use a maths alphabet up for a single symbol (it is not hard to plough through the 16 available), you can define a macro to access the symbol by tweaking [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406/) and the relevant commands from `pifont`. Combining this with the information from Heiko Oberdiek's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb egreg: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406/
\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Pimathsymbol[3][\mathord]{%
  #1{\@Pimathsymbol{#2}{#3}}}
\def\@Pimathsymbol#1#2{\mathchoice
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\sf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\ssf@size}}
\def\@Pim@thsymbol#1#2#3{%
  \mbox{\fontsize{#3}{#3}\Piitsymbol{#1}{#2}}}
% ateb Heiko Oberdiek: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354435/
\newif\iftx@libertine
\newif\iftx@minion
\newif\iftx@coch
% pifont.sty
\newcommand{\Piitfont}[1]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontencoding{U}%
\fontseries{m}\fontshape{it}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\Piitsymbol}[2]{{\Piitfont{#1}\char#2}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\newplus}{\Pimathsymbol[\mathbin]{ntxmia}{253}}

\begin{document}

\[
      + \newplus
\]


\end{document}
```

[image: plus and new plus]